# Event tracking with Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Is the following setup of Google Tag Manager and Analytics correct regarding the variable use, naming etc.

Tag: GA tracking code

Tag: Goals w. macro below

Macro: (As specified in post) Event Action > eventAction; Event Category > eventCategory; Event Label > eventLabel etc.

Rules: GA Event > GAevent

Triggered by JS: dataLayer.push({ 'event':'GAevent', 'eventCategory':'Forms', 'eventAction':'Send', 'eventLabel':'Request' })

In Google Analytics:

1st Goal: Category > Forms; Action > Send; Label > Request Form
2nd Goal: Category > Forms; Action > Send; Label > Contact Form

Answer (score 1):

Have you created a tag for Google Analytics Event?

You'll have to map the event category to eventCategory, etc. And then set the rule to GA Event equal to GAevent.(see attached)[image: GTM]